# Hive/Hadoop - lateral view with array of object

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I am really new to Hive, and I would like to create a view from my json (see below) I tried to use explode and then json_tuple but I don't really understand everythings here.

Json :

```
{ "envelope": {
  "MetaData": {
    "SpecificMetaData":[{"key":"te","value":"0"}, {"key":"tere","value":"5"}],
    "ReferencePointDeltaAboveGroundM":0.5
    }
  },
  "path":{
    "positionEstimate":[{"longitudeDeg":1.3892306300761323,"latitudeDeg":43.5653731709185}, {"longitudeDeg":1.3892306300761323,"latitudeDeg":43.5653731709185}]
  }
}
```

What I tried. I didn't find good examples for the same kind of array object.

```
create external table fleet_fh ( breadcrumbs string)
location 's3://.../';

    CREATE VIEW fleetinfo_fh AS
    SELECT envelope, longitudeDeg, latitudeDeg, INPUT__FILE__NAME as filenm
    FROM fleet_fh ac
    LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(ac.envelope, 'MetaData') s as MetaData, LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(s.MetaData, 'SpecificMetaData', 'ReferencePointDeltaAboveGroundM') v as SpecificMetaData, ReferencePointDeltaAboveGroundM, LATERAL VIEW explode(v.SpecificMetaData) vs, LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(vs, 'key', 'value');
    LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(ac.path,'positionEstimate') r as positionEstimate, LATERAL VIEW explode(r.positionEstimate) l, LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(l, 'longitudeDeg', 'latitudeDeg')
```

Moreover, is there any way to test hive command with an interface ?